# C Programming. Program crashing when trying to read and write

Tags: c

I'm having a hard time figuring this problem right now... In one of my functions to copy a file, it always crashes while trying to read from one file to another. Also I'm a beginner, so sorry for any mistakes I've done.

```
int file_copy(void)
{
    char path_new[MAX_PATH];

    file_load();

    printf("New name: ");
    scanf("%s", path_new);               // <---- Crash right after entering a new path

    FILE *fr_source, *fw_target;

    if (((fr_source = fopen(path_current, "r")) && (fw_target = fopen(path_new, "w"))) == NULL) {
        printf("Error while opening one of these files");
        exit(6);
    }

    int c;

    while((c = getc(fr_source)) != EOF) {
        fputc(c, fw_target);
    }

    printf("File copied successfully.\n");

    if ((fclose(path_current)) && (fclose(path_new)) == EOF) {
        printf("Error while closing one of these files");
        exit(7);
    }

    return 0;
}

int file_load(void)
{
   printf("Path to current file: ");
   scanf("%s", path_current);

   if (file_access(path_current) != 0)
       exit(2);

   return 0;
}

int file_access(char path[])
{
    if ((access(path, F_OK)) != 0) {
       printf("ERROR = %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
Now it works after separating this two:

```
if ((fr_source = fopen(path_current, "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error while opening one of these files");
    exit(6);
}

if ((fw_target = fopen(path_new, "w")) == NULL) {
    printf("Error while opening '%s'\n", path_new);
    exit(6);
}
```

Comment: Check the `fopen` part, `&&` returns an integer (boolean)  like 0 or 1, not a pointer like `NULL`

Comment: In `scanf("%s", path_new);` where you say it crashed, either you are entering more data than allowed, or, the previous call to `file_load();` (which we don't see) caused colateral damage.

Comment: Isn't that scanf("%s", path_new); needs to be `scanf("%s", &path_new);`??

Comment: @LethalProgrammer-- No. Array names decay to pointers to their first elements in C, so you should not use the address operator `&` when reading strings into arrays with `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line

```
if (((fr_source = fopen(path_current, "r")) && (fw_target = fopen(path_new, "w"))) == NULL) {
```

to

```
if (((fr_source = fopen(path_current, "r")) == NULL) || ((fw_target = fopen(path_new, "w")) == NULL)) {
```

Similarly,

```
if ((fclose(path_current)) && (fclose(path_new)) == EOF) {
```

should be

```
if ((fclose(fr_source) == EOF) || (fclose(fw_target) == EOF)) {
```

Using the format `(ptr1 && ptr2) == NULL` is confusing, and throws warnings on many compilers (certainly if you use `gcc -Wall -pedantic`, which I do).

In addition, `int fclose(FILE*)`, takes an open file pointer, not a string, as its argument.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your tip, I've tried it and the crash stopped but now it's telling me that one if these files can't be opened.

Comment: That's probably because I made a typo. In my opening files line, they should both be `== NULL` (the first one was in error). I will edit.

Comment: After changing it a little bit, I've got it working now. Thank you for your tips.